# Tabulator's "time" sorter doesn't sort correctly with hh:mm:ss format

Tags: tabulator

I have moment.js loaded and datetime sorting working - this seems to require both a formatter and a sorter FWIW.  But for "time" sorting, I'm simply trying to have data come in as strings with this format:

"hh:mm:ss"

And then, using the "time" sorter, I configure it thusly:

```
{'field': 'wall_time', 'title': 'wall_time', 'sorter': 'time', 'sorterParams': {'format': 'hh:mm:ss'}}
```

The problem is, I get incorrect sort ordering:

[image: Bad time sort screenshot]

Is there any way to debug this further?

Addendum:  Note that my columns and rows are being loaded after table creation in an Ajax call - this may have an impact on sort behavior:

```
  table.setColumns(response.cols);
  table.setData(response.rows);
```

Comment: Why are your hours greater than 24?  I think that is your issue, just testing an example I can sort correctly when the times are valid.  However, if I use times that are invalid, it doesn't sort.  https://jsfiddle.net/nrayburn/6wygod1c/21/

Comment: thanks, this is intended to be a timedelta (but I thought that I could get away with this!) - the problem with using a "datetimediff" - which seems natural, is that I want the reference date to be another field...and that doesn't seem possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your times are not valid times, they cannot be converted to a standard 24 hour time.  The built-in sorter will not work for you.  You have to create your own.  You can read more about custom sorters here, http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/sort#func.

Here is something that I believe will work for you.  https://jsfiddle.net/nrayburn/6wygod1c/29/

The general idea is to change your column to use your custom sorter.  Create a custom sorter that returns the diff between the two values being compared.

```
  {
    field: 'time',
    name: 'Time',
    sorter: customSorter
  }

function customSorter(a, b){
    const aArray = a.split(':');
    const bArray = b.split(':');
    let diff = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        if (aArray[i] !== bArray[i]){
            diff = bArray[i] - aArray[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    return diff;
}
```

Because this uses a custom sorter, you do not need to include moment.js anymore.